# Can I extract a function to a utils file and then use it in a React component while passing a function from the component to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a function getFontColor(), that I would like to extract to a utils folder, and call it in a component. This function though, uses a function that is inside my component (getBgColor()). How do I pass getBgColor to the util function and how to I call the util function in my component?

Util function I want to extract:

```
  export const getFontColor = () => {
    const bgColor = getBgColor();   
    return something;
  };
```

Function getBgColor() which is inside the component:

```
  const getBgColor = () => {
    return something
  };
```

Calling the util function:

```
 <StyledTitle color={getFontColor}>
   {node.label}
 </StyledTitle>
```

How can I communicate those? The main issue, is how do I pass the getBgColor to the external function?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your `getBgColor`-function to your utils-function. In Javascript functions are first class objects, so they behave like any other object, such as an int or a list. That means that you can use functions as arguments to other functions.

```js
// utils.js
export const getFontColor = async (props) => {
  const fontColor = await getFontColorAsync(props);
  return fontColor;
}

const getFontColorAsync = async ({ getBgColor }) => {
  const bgColor = getBgColor();  
  return something;
}
```

```js
//component.jsx
import { getFontColor } from "./utils.js"

function Component() {
  const getBgColor = () => {
    return something;
  };

  const fontColor = getFontColor({ getBgColor });

  return (
    <StyledTitle color={fontColor}>
      {node.label}
    </StyledTitle>
  );
}
```

Comment: Implementing this but getting a dispatch exemption. :S Also needed to to the getFontColor async for it to work!

Comment: Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: n is not a function. (In 'n()', 'n' is undefined)

Comment: Checkout my adapted response.

Comment: Syntax error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (30:21). It's a weird one.

Comment: Try it again with the updated answer. Now it will work, but I think you have to rethink your code. await can only be used inside an async function.

Comment: It doesn't but I will keep investigating it. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction :)

Comment: Checkout the response again. You can hide the async call in utils-module.